# OAuth with Active Directory Single Sign On

Tags: single-sign-on, oauth, rest, activedirectory

I am writing a Java App that will integrate with Salesforce using OAUTH + REST. In normal circumstances without any single sign on everything is cool.

But the same app might be used to work with Salesforce orgs, where users are logging in to their machines + Salesforce via Active Directory credentials.

In such circumstances, will user be ever directed to Salesforce login screen ? Or they will be always taken to authorisation page (i.e. "Approve/Deny") directly ?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_for_Desktop_and_Mobile_Applications_using_SAML_and_OAuth

Comment: Thanks Mike, that is all I need ! hate my bad google search string which couldn't find this page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Single Sign-On for Desktop and Mobile Applications using SAML and OAUTH](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_for_Desktop_and_Mobile_Applications_using_SAML_and_OAuth), you can get your application to send the user to just the accept/deny page directly by using a web browser internal to your application. This is how the Chatter Desktop application and other Salesforce offerings work.

Comment: Key take away is 'My Domain', which chatter desktop app is offering as optional configuration to work across different env.